# A doubt with respect to equilibrium in heterogeneous system

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, material-science, phase-transition

This is particularly with regard to "Equilibrium in heterogeneous systems",it is given that he stable phase forms of pure A and ppure B at a given temperature and pressure can be denoted as $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively.Now what I really do not understand is,"The first step in drawing the free energy curve of the fcc $\alpha$ phase is therefore to convert stable bcc arrangement of B atoms into unstable fcc arrangement."Please explain me why it is so.[image]

Comment: So you compare like arrangement to like arrangement before starting to try an mix them.

Comment: @JonCuster Can you elaborate slightly?

Comment: Say A is stable in the fcc structure, and B is bcc. You need to know 'how happy' an A atom is sitting on a bcc site, since that is a different environment from an fcc site. You do that by evaluating the free energy of A as a bcc crystal. Standard Gibbs free energies of elements in a variety of crystal structures have been tabulated for use in computational phase diagram evaluations.